# angular directive to create a spring like animation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a button which I am trying to give a spring like effect when user drags it down.

Having not found any direct spring like animation in animate.css, I am trying to add `slideInDown` class to the button when user starts dragging and `slideInUp` class when user stops dragging.

However, I am not sure if I am adding those classes the right way i.e directive works fine otherwise but just the animation classes are not added.

This is what my directive looks like:

```
.directive('draggable', function ($animate) {
  return function(scope, element) {
       var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

        var el = element[0];
        console.log(el)
        el.draggable = true;
        element.css({
       position: 'relative',
       cursor: 'pointer'
      });
        el.addEventListener(
            'dragstart',
            function(e) {

              $animate.addClass(el, "slideInDown")    
                return false;
            },
            false
        );

        el.addEventListener(
            'dragend',
            function(e) {
              $animate.removeClass(el, "slideInDown")
              $animate.addClass(el, "slideInUp")


                //this.classList.add('animated slideInUp');

               scope.checkBill();
                return false;
            },
            false
        );
    }
})
```

How do I get it working? Where do I seem to have gone wrong?

Comment: did you tried `scope.$apply()` after adding or removing class?

Comment: @PankajParkar: I did. It made no difference.